# GBRT Hyperparameter Tuning using GridSearchCV

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm running GridSearchCV to find the best parameters for GradientBoostingRegressor.

The tutorial given was to use MSE for scoring.

```
gs_cv = GridSearchCV(est, param_grid, scoring='mean_squared_error', n_jobs=4).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Is it possible to use other own defined scoring such as Root Mean Squared Logarithmic Error (RMSLE) to get the best hyperparameters?

```
def rmsle(predicted, actual, size):
    return np.sqrt(np.nansum(np.square(np.log(predicted + 1) - np.log(actual + 1)))/float(size))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a [custom scorer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#defining-your-scoring-strategy-from-score-functions). In your case it would look like this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer

scorer = make_scorer(rmsle, greater_is_better=False, size=10)
grid = GridSearchCV(est, param_grid, scoring=scorer)
```